# Animating Header Using Transform React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, interpolation, react-animated

Using React Native, I am trying to mimic the below animation. The header *(Map Pin and Stamba Hotel Tbilisi)* scrolls up with the FlatList, but then if the user scrolls down the header is immediately scrolled down with the FlatList. Kindly note this animation is adhering to the SareAreaView.

[image]

The problems I am having are the following;

1. When the user scrolls up the FlatList doesn't go with it, therefore, leaving a blank white area.
2. When the user scrolls back down the Header is not immediately scrolling down.
3. The header does not go under the SafeAreaView

### COMPONENT TREE

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ zIndex: 1, flex: 1 }}>
    <Animated.View style={[styles.header, { transform: [{ translateY }] }]}>
      <HomeHeader2 />
    </Animated.View>
    {loading ? 
      <View/> : <FlatList/>
    }
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

### HANDLING ANIMATION

```
// FLATLIST PROP TO HANDLE ANIMATION
onScroll={ Animated.event([{nativeEvent:
  { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }], {
      useNativeDriver: false,
  })
}
// INTERPOLATE OVER SCROLLY
  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const translateY = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50],
    outputRange: [0, -50],
    extrapolateRight: "clamp",
  });
```

### STYLING

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "relative", // AS SHOULD BE UNDER SAFEAREAVIEW
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
  },
});
```

Am I on the right track here or is there a better approach?